Upgradable contract is sucessfully created and verified but token doesn’t shows up at bsc scan the name and symbol
Deployed and verified using remix
The Name and symbol are unavlaible in token search, while same code works on testnets, any help will be grateful the code was got from openzeppling contract wizard and verified by remix plugin
deployment link https://bscscan.com/address/0xda9c30737acb2ab72800e063e9ea792895d17df3 while it does show on sepolia https://sepolia.etherscan.io/tx/0x0562440256438ae77a6818474098fcdaa2a84f60610f7ea08fdd9099c24dcdd6

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The block scanner sometimes doesn't recognize that your contract is an ERC20 before you try to mint something.
Try minting a few tokens for yourself and let the explorer pick it up.

will burning help?
